# how send a data to AXI STREAM VIP?

Tags: vip

I send req(with queue of data) to driver from sequence
and in the driver, I call to task from API(call it write_data) - end sent the data [axi4stream_cfg_object.axi4stream_api_vif.write_data(req_item.data);//data is queue]
and in the api- I call task from mst_agent: automatic send_a_packet(xil_axi4stream_uint num_words)

but I dont know how the mistake with the send data, and what is **num_words**??

can you help me please?

---